# How to make this code copy from Single Linked list to array not array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, linked-list

I'm writing code to convert a single `LinkedList<Integer>` to an array.

My code converts it to an 'ArrayList' not a normal array (`int[]`).

```
public class CopyToArrayLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> linkedlist = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        linkedlist.add(1);
        linkedlist.add(2);
        linkedlist.add(3);
        linkedlist.add(4);
        linkedlist.add(5);

        Integer[] array = linkedlist.toArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < linkedlist.size(); i++){
        System.out.println( linkedlist.get(i)); }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what keeps you from writing other code?

Comment: when I create a new array, I couldn't make a copy for the element.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Where's the code to try that out?

Comment: Please add all such information to the question itself. And what is the problem with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, try like

```
Integer[] array = linkedlist.toArray(new Integer[linkedlist.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the build in toArray function thats available in the `List` api?

```
Integer[] array = linkedlist.toArray(new Integer[0]);

for (Integer i : array) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Note that loop would throw a `NullPointerException` if any elements are null.

Comment: @AndyTurner huh? I just tested it. It does not throw an NPE if there are no elements. Only if the list itself or the array itself is null.

Comment: @StephanHogenboom Try it with `List<Integer> linkedlist = Arrays.asList(1,2,null,3);` or just `linkedlist.add(null);` to see what Andy refers to. If the linked lsit itself contains null as an element you will get a NPE.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS @Andy Turner thanks for clarifying! I changed `int` to `Integer` so it does no throw a NPE if it tries to unbox it.